# Como entender a mensagem de erro do servidor WildFly8x?

Tags: wildfly

Meu projeto se trata um maven com JSF está funcionando normalmente mas ele gera um erro com eu adiciono o artefato do Primefaces;

```
<!-- PrimeFaces (biblioteca de componentes) -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

veja a mensagem de erro

```
04:04:04,464 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-6) Inicializando Mojarra 2.2.8-jbossorg-1 20140822-1131 para o contexto '/Terezinha.Bandeira'
04:04:06,138 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-6) Critical error during deployment: : com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
  Source Document: vfs:/C:/Users/mary/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/standalone/deployments/Terezinha.Bandeira.war/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-3.5.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Class 'org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUploadRenderer' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:339) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.RenderKitConfigProcessor.addRenderers(RenderKitConfigProcessor.java:313) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.RenderKitConfigProcessor.process(RenderKitConfigProcessor.java:179) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ManagedBeanConfigProcessor.process(ManagedBeanConfigProcessor.java:270) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ValidatorConfigProcessor.process(ValidatorConfigProcessor.java:120) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ConverterConfigProcessor.process(ConverterConfigProcessor.java:126) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ComponentConfigProcessor.process(ComponentConfigProcessor.java:117) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:344) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:239) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:435) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:221) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:194) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.classHasAnnotations(Util.java:1005) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationInstanceFactoryMetadataMap.onPut(ApplicationInstanceFactoryMetadataMap.java:75) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationInstanceFactoryMetadataMap.onPut(ApplicationInstanceFactoryMetadataMap.java:43) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.util.MetadataWrapperMap.put(MetadataWrapperMap.java:91) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.loadClass(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:378) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:278) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem from [Module "deployment.Terezinha.Bandeira.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    ... 36 more

04:04:06,144 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/Terezinha.Bandeira": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/Terezinha.Bandeira": Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
  Source Document: vfs:/C:/Users/mary/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/standalone/deployments/Terezinha.Bandeira.war/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-3.5.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Class 'org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUploadRenderer' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:223)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
  Source Document: vfs:/C:/Users/mary/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/standalone/deployments/Terezinha.Bandeira.war/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-3.5.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Class 'org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUploadRenderer' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:280)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:194)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
  Source Document: vfs:/C:/Users/mary/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/standalone/deployments/Terezinha.Bandeira.war/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-3.5.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Class 'org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUploadRenderer' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:339)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.RenderKitConfigProcessor.addRenderers(RenderKitConfigProcessor.java:313)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.RenderKitConfigProcessor.process(RenderKitConfigProcessor.java:179)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ManagedBeanConfigProcessor.process(ManagedBeanConfigProcessor.java:270)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ValidatorConfigProcessor.process(ValidatorConfigProcessor.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ConverterConfigProcessor.process(ConverterConfigProcessor.java:126)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ComponentConfigProcessor.process(ComponentConfigProcessor.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:344)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:239)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:435)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:221)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.classHasAnnotations(Util.java:1005)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationInstanceFactoryMetadataMap.onPut(ApplicationInstanceFactoryMetadataMap.java:75)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationInstanceFactoryMetadataMap.onPut(ApplicationInstanceFactoryMetadataMap.java:43)
    at com.sun.faces.util.MetadataWrapperMap.put(MetadataWrapperMap.java:91)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.loadClass(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:378)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:278)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem from [Module "deployment.Terezinha.Bandeira.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    ... 36 more

04:04:06,156 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "Terezinha.Bandeira.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host.\"/Terezinha.Bandeira\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host.\"/Terezinha.Bandeira\": Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
  Source Document: vfs:/C:/Users/mary/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/standalone/deployments/Terezinha.Bandeira.war/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-3.5.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Class 'org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUploadRenderer' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
  Source Document: vfs:/C:/Users/mary/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/standalone/deployments/Terezinha.Bandeira.war/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-3.5.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Class 'org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUploadRenderer' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem
    Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
  Source Document: vfs:/C:/Users/mary/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/standalone/deployments/Terezinha.Bandeira.war/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-3.5.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Class 'org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUploadRenderer' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem from [Module \"deployment.Terezinha.Bandeira.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
04:04:06,204 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "Terezinha.Bandeira.war" (runtime-name : "Terezinha.Bandeira.war")
04:04:06,205 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/Terezinha.Bandeira": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/Terezinha.Bandeira": Failed to start service

04:04:06,283 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
04:04:06,283 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
04:04:06,283 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: WildFly 8.2.1.Final "Tweek" started (with errors) in 10044ms - Started 251 of 309 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 92 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
04:04:06,439 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010418: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = Terezinha.Bandeira.war_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1
04:04:06,463 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-2) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
04:04:06,582 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment Terezinha.Bandeira.war (runtime-name: Terezinha.Bandeira.war) in 148ms
04:04:06,717 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018558: Undeployed "Terezinha.Bandeira.war" (runtime-name: "Terezinha.Bandeira.war")
04:04:06,718 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."Terezinha.Bandeira.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Terezinha.Bandeira.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."Terezinha.Bandeira.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Terezinha.Bandeira.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."Terezinha.Bandeira.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Terezinha.Bandeira.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."Terezinha.Bandeira.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Terezinha.Bandeira.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."Terezinha.Bandeira.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Terezinha.Bandeira.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/Terezinha.Bandeira" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Terezinha.Bandeira.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/Terezinha.Bandeira"

04:04:11,235 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015003: Found Terezinha.Bandeira.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called Terezinha.Bandeira.war.dodeploy
```

mesmo com a mensagem de erro ele funciona normalmente, mas eu queri poder copilar sem ter ficar gerando essa mensagem de erro.

Estou usando o servidor WildFly8x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não está fazendo exclusion dessa depêndencia?

    commons-fileupload
    commons-fileupload

Caso não esteja tente adicioná-la, o componente FileUploadRenderer está utilizando o FileItem dela que não está sendo encontrado.